# Meteor take too long to response a call

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a peculiar issue, When I call a meteor method on the frontend, Meteor executes and returns the method but my frontend doesn't execute the callback, but It only happens on my production app, on locally the same code works and executes the callback.

At this point, the issue will be maybe optimization but, Is not, because I add some `console.time` to my backend and the execution time is even faster than my local meteor instance, in 100ms the return method is called, in local is like 500ms.

Example:
frontend

```
Meteor.call("method1", (err, res) => {
    console.log("Done :)")
  })
```

backend

```
Meteor.methods({method1() {
    console.time("test")
    // do something
    console.timeEnd("test")
    return true
  }
})
```

Comment: I alredy tried using Meteor.apply, or using Meteor.defear to long process and still without working

Comment: I would open the WS tab in the network tab of the dev console in your browser and see which ddp messages are being sent back and forth. Since it only happens in your prod, I would think it is related to networking. Do subscriptions work?

Comment: I second the comment on looking in the WS tab, but I'd also suggest looking for the `updated` and `result` messages for the method you called. In some situations, one or the other of these fails to return due to issues with the oplog.

When this happens, are you able to continue executing method calls?

Comment: Yes, I got a result, but the problem is the time between the function return and the response of meteor, I finally fixed it by updating meteor to the last version, I think that they do it on purpose.